# How to rotate a label, textbox or picturebox during runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, rotation

Is that possible to rotate a label, textbox, or picturebox during runtime by giving angle values?

Comment: Nope, for this functionality, you might consider WPF. For winforms, you will probably need to override the OnPaint methods and roll your own implementation....Why would you want to do such a thing anyway? this does not seem like a user-friendly thing to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in WinForms, no. You can do it if you use WPF.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project) article *[Customized Text - Orientated Controls in C# - Part I (Label Control)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8383/Customized-Text-Orientated-Controls-in-C-Part-I-La)*:

> Introduction
>
> There are many ways in which text can be displayed. But most common ways are showing it in the path of straight line, arc, and circle. The Label which comes with NET can only display the text in the path of a straight line. This control can do that in all the main three methods, with rotation angle. Also, text can be displayed in a direction which we are interested in.